# This tab is not available on mobile

Tags: microsoft-teams

Recently, our (published) app stopped working on mobile, with the above message, "This tab is not available on mobile". The app is a custom teams tab basically.

What can be causing this issue?

From our side, we have not changed anything (neither in the manifest nor in the hosting).
Are there some changes in the teams policy or maybe some new requirements or changes?

In the desktop/web client the app works like it did before. On the mobile, if you try to click a link to the app tab, it shows this notification tooltip "not available on mobile" instead of opening the tab.

```
Manifest version: 1.9
"@microsoft/teams-js": "^1.12.1",
```

Not sure, if the versions are related, the mobile client shows that tooltip without even trying to open the tab.

It looks like the problem appeared with some latest update of the Teams client. The app is still working fine with Teams client from June 2022, but starts showing this message "tab is not available on mobile" if the Teams mobile client is updated to the latest version.

I have noticed that now there is a button to "Add an app.." in the teams app on mobile. Are there some new requirements for existing apps because of this maybe (so that existing apps won't work on mobile unless adapted)?

Related observation: all app tabs created disappeared on "More..." tab after mobile teams client is updated

Appreciate any insights what might be causing the issue?

[image]

Comment: Could you please track this issue here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/1387

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Sure. just wanted to get some response, as we also recently got a notification from the store that our app may be suspended because of this, and we are not sure what happened, it seems that there wasn't any change from our side :)

Comment: This question is being tracked on - https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/1387. Please check this thread for updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution here from the linked issue if somebody else faces it. The message was appearing because `websiteUrl` property was not set in the tab configuration. It is now [required for the tab to appear in the mobile client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/design/tabs-mobile). Setting this property in the tab configuration resolves the issue.

Comment: where exactly did you add the `websiteUrl` property and what is the value?

Comment: @cortex you need to set it when setting configuration for the new tab, somewhere around the `microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings(....)`, where you set the `contentUrl` property. The exact place depends on your app. I.e. every time you set contentUrl you should also set websiteUrl.